# How to declare forall quantifiers in SMTLIB / Z3 / CVC4?

Tags: z3, smt, sat, cvc4

I'm stuck on how to how to create a statement in SMTLIB2 that asserts something like

```
forall x < 100, f(x) = 100
```

This property would be check a function that adds 1 to all numbers less than 100 recursively:

```
(define-fun-rec incUntil100 ((x Int)) Int  
    (ite 
        (= x 100) 
        100
        (incUntil100 (+ x 1))
    )
)
```

I read through the [Z3 tutorial on quantifiers and patterns](https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial), but that didn't seem to get me much anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SMTLib, you'd write that property as follows:

```
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (=> (< x 100) (= (incUntil100 x) 100))))
(check-sat)
```

But if you try this, you'll see that z3 will loop forever and CVC4 will tell you `unknown` as the answer. While you can define and assert these sorts of functions in SMTLib, solver support for actual proofs is rather weak, as they do not do induction out-of-the box.

If proving properties of recursive functions is your goal, SMT-solvers are not a good choice; instead look into theorem provers such as Isabelle, HOL, Coq, Lean, ACL2, etc.; which are built for that very purpose.

Comment: I can write proofs in Coq, but I was hoping to automate this process. Is there no good way of automating quantified SMT formulae?

Comment: Currently, patterns are the only mechanism to get any reasonable output from quantified proofs. There are some examples here https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h28 but it's rather tricky to make it do anything fancy; especially in the presence of recursive functions like you have. Also keep in mind that z3 and cvc4 will have different levels of support, so consistency isn't guaranteed either.